# CentOS 7 undefined symbol: ompi_mpi_logical8

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, openmpi

I'm trying to install a python(3) package which depends on `mpi4py` on a `CentOS 7` machine.

I have tried multiple ways of doing everything, even start from clean `virtualenvs` but I keep getting:

```
ImportError: $PATH_TO_VENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: ompi_mpi_logical8
```

This comes up even if, after a successful installation through `pip`, I just write in the interpreter:

```
>>> import mpi4py
>>> from mpi4py import MPI
```

Has anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found that I have to install the library using the `env MPICC=` prefix.

```sh
env MPICC=/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpicc pip install --no-cache-dir mpi4py
```

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem today, this is how I solve it:
conda install mpi4py

The following packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
mpi-1.0                    |          openmpi           4 KB  https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge
mpi4py-3.0.3               |   py37hbfacf26_1         647 KB  https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge
openmpi-4.0.3              |       hdf1f1ad_1         3.9 MB  https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:         4.6 MB
```

I think either missing mpi-1.0 or an out-dated openmpi will cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mpi4py` was installed while a different than the current version of MPI was used.

```
pip uninstall mpi4py
pip install --no-cache-dir mpi4py
```

The above should resolve the problem. Maybe resourcing the virtualenv is neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this I had to NOT use OpenMPI 4.0.0 nor 4.0.3 but we have mpich 3.2.1 as a module available and that worked, i.e., the `undefined symbol` error went away.