# Scientific Linux 7.4: undefined symbol: ompi_mpi_logical8 error

Tags: python-3.x, mpi, openmpi, mpi4py, mpich

I am trying to run a Python Package that uses MPI for running tasks in parallel.

as per the package's [`guidelines`](https://github.com/nickkid/ParaCopasi/blob/main/README.md); I installed MPICH 4.2.0, followed my mpi4py.

However, after running their example command, I get the following response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sGC_parameter_estimation.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mpi4py.futures import MPIPoolExecutor
  File "/home/people/hkaya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpi4py/futures/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .pool import MPIPoolExecutor
  File "/home/people/hkaya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpi4py/futures/pool.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _lib
  File "/home/people/hkaya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpi4py/futures/_lib.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .. import MPI
ImportError: /home/people/hkaya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: ompi_mpi_logical8
```

when I run "ldd" for the said .so file; here is the output:

```
ldd /home/people/hkaya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffefd45f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b8515af4000)
    libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00002b8515cf9000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b8516221000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b851643d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055806dd65000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00002b8516801000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b8516a04000)
```

Although running -objdump -tT gives a very long list, where ompi_mpi_logical8 is included with an "*UND*" tag.

I also tried reinstalling mpi4py as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129738/centos-7-undefined-symbol-ompi-mpi-logical8), which did not resolve my issue. In fact, I noticed that mpi4py was installed in a different directory /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages from the one that the package was trying to import MPI from.

So, I am guessing that there is a clash between two mpi4py versions. But I cannot say for sure.

mpiexec --version gives two different outputs for when I am root vs not.

In root:

mpiexec (OpenRTE) 4.1.2

Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/

When I'm in my local home directory:

HYDRA build details:
Version:                                 4.2.0rc2
Release Date:                            Tue Jan 16 14:53:48 CST 2024
CC:                              gcc -std=gnu99
Configure options:                       '--disable-option-checking' '--prefix=/home/people/hkaya/mpich-install' '--with-hwloc=embedded' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=/home/people/hkaya/Downloads/mpich-4.2.0rc2/src/pm/hydra' 'CC=gcc -std=gnu99' 'CFLAGS= -O2' 'LDFLAGS=' 'LIBS=' 'CPPFLAGS= -DNETMOD_INLINE=**netmod_inline_ofi** -I/temp/hkaya/mpich-4.1.2/src/mpl/include -I/home/people/hkaya/Downloads/mpich-4.2.0rc2/src/mpl/include -I/home/people/hkaya/Downloads/mpich-4.2.0rc2/modules/json-c -I/temp/hkaya/mpich-4.1.2/modules/json-c -I/home/people/hkaya/Downloads/mpich-4.2.0rc2/modules/hwloc/include -I/temp/hkaya/mpich-4.1.2/modules/hwloc/include -D_REENTRANT -I/temp/hkaya/mpich-4.1.2/src/mpi/romio/include -I/home/people/hkaya/Downloads/mpich-4.2.0rc2/src/pmi/include -I/temp/hkaya/mpich-4.1.2/src/pmi/include -I/temp/hkaya/mpich-4.1.2/modules/yaksa/src/frontend/include -I/home/people/hkaya/Downloads/mpich-4.2.0rc2/modules/yaksa/src/frontend/include -I/temp/hkaya/mpich-4.1.2/modules/libfabric/include -I/home/people/hkaya/Downloads/mpich-4.2.0rc2/modules/libfabric/include'
Process Manager:                         pmi
Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
Topology libraries available:            hwloc
Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
Demux engines available:                 poll select

So, my question is: how can solve this contradiction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you install MPICH 4.2? It appears the standard system package for SL 7.4 is MPICH 3.03; I would install that instead.

Comment: You're using Python 3.6, while the linked website of your package mentioned it's been tested on Python 3.7 and 3.8. And your mpi4py version might be too recent for any of the older Python versions, though it could very well work. If you remove your 4.2 MPICH and install the system version, perhaps try a slightly older mpi4py version as well: the 3.0.z series might more match your system setup.

Comment: Note that the linked package, ParaCopasi, is about 2.5 years old and seems unmaintained, while the underlying Copasi package (separate install) has much newer versions. So again, you might want to match an older Copasi package with ParaCopasi for compatibility (perhaps a newer version works, but that's not guaranteed).

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the input! I will definitely start by installing the proper versions and let you know the outcome :)

Comment: An alternative could be to try and use (mini)Conda. If you set up a proper Conda environment, you can use a more recent Python version (e.g., 3.8, to match ParaCopasi), and install mpi4py with its MPI library in one go: `conda create -n myenv mpi4py python=3.8`. Perhaps Copasi is even installable through Conda (possibly on a separate channel).

Comment: `mpi4py` was built for Open MPI, so this is the library you shoud use. If you want to use `MPICH`, then you will have to rebuilt `mpi4py`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @9769953 thanks again! after following your suggestions, it is no longer returning the undefined symbol error

Comment: Good to hear. So does everything work properly now?